# TIdFTP corrupted file after upload

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, indy10

Recently we changed the company that hosts our domain from Windows to Linux hosting. Since then, any file i upload using TIdFTP is uploaded without errors, but when i try to download this file, the file is corrupted. For instance, i upload a ZIP file, and when i try to download, i can't expand the ZIP.

The error won't happen if i use a regular FTP client, like Filezilla.

Is there any configuration i could try in TIdFTP to avoid this issue ?

Nothing changed on my code as below :

```
    ftp.host := 'ftp.myhost.com';
    ftp.Username := 'myusername';
    ftp.password := 'mypassword';
    ftp.Connect();
    ftp.ChangeDir('public_html/downloads');
    ftp.Put('c:\myfile.zip','myfile.zip');
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `TransferType` property value in your IdFTP component? It should be `ftBinary` for transferring archives.

Comment: @Miamy This fixed the issue ! Please post as answer, i'll accept. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TransferType` property value of the IdFTP component should be `ftBinary` for transferring archives.

Comment: The `TIdFTP.TransferType` property is set to `ftAscii` by default, which causes linebreaks to change when files are transferred across platform boundaries. You need to set the `TransferType` to `ftBinary` when transferring non-textual files, such as Zip archives, or if you just don't want linebreaks to change.